# Using the same setter multiple times cause too many rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am writing a react native project which there are articles. I use flatlist to show each article. I split the articles into words and each word is clickable. Clicking a word sets a modal visible. The problem is that once I click on one word, it makes all other words rerender which causes a performance issue.

I used react memo but it didnt work.

Edit:
example code without flatlists to keep it simple:

```
export default function Main() {

  const [wordModalVisible, setWordModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleTextPress = () => {
    setWordModalVisible(true);
  };

  interface TextProps {
    onPress: () => void;
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }

  const MyText: React.FC<TextProps> = ({ onPress, children }) => {
    return <Text onPress={onPress}>{children}</Text>;
  };


  return (
    <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} style={styles.contentText}>
      <MyText onPress={handleTextPress}>Text 1</MyText>
      <MyText onPress={handleTextPress}>Text 2</MyText>
      <MyText onPress={handleTextPress}>Text 3</MyText>
      <MyText onPress={handleTextPress}>Text 4</MyText>
      <MyText onPress={handleTextPress}>Text 5</MyText>
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please make a reproducible example with some code so we can help you?

Comment: From the code above, it is unclear where your state resides. If it resides in the higher level container, then it perfectly makes sense that when you change the state, all the children, including all your `MyText` components, are re-rendered.

Comment: @RAllen I updated the code. Is it clear like this?

Comment: @AnarMamedov yep, it looks exactly as I expected. Your `main` component and everything inside is re-rendered every time you set `wordModalVisible` state. You need to move this state into a separate component `Modal` and pass its setter into text things. In this case only the `Modal` component will re-render if the state is set.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment, I wasn't right. You have to keep the state in the `Main`, however, you need to wrap your `MyText` components in `React.memo`.

This will guarantee that `MyText` components are re-rendered only if their props are changed.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyText = React.memo(() => {
  console.log('MyText render');
  return <div>MyText</div>;
});

const Main = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  return <div>
    <div onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)}>Click me</div>
    <MyText/>
    <MyText/>
    <MyText/>    
    {modalVisible ? <div>The Modal is visible now</div> : null}
  </div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Main/>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as I am using react native, not react. I tried putting mytext out of main however they all kept re-rendering every time i clicked on one of them

Comment: @AnarMamedov why is this a problem that `MyText` components are re-rendering? Are the texts extra large? You said that it is a performance issue. How exactly the performance issue looks? I guess the actual problem could be that `adjustsFontSizeToFit` is trying to find the most suitable font size and hence re-renders everything. Try to switch it off and check if the performance is better.

Comment: the texts are really large considering them being articles. That’s what causes a performance issue. At least 300 words get re rendered every time

Comment: Then the only option I can think of is to place all the texts into one container and put the modal and its state into another. This will isolate modal container re-rendering from text container re-rendering.